# Error npm start

Tags: nodejs, api, google-hoja-de-cálculo, npm

Estoy tratando de seguir el `Codelab` del `excel de google`, porque quiero implementar la `API` de google y me da el siguiente error que no se como solucionarlo.

```
C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start> npm start
```

> sheets-api-codelab@1.0.0 start C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start
>   nodemon server.js
>
> [nodemon] 1.10.2 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>   [nodemon] watching: *.* [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
>   C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:25
>         throw new Error('Please install sqlite3 package manually');
>         ^
>
> Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually
>       at new ConnectionManager (C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:25:13)
>       at new SqliteDialect (C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\index.js:12:28)
>       at new Sequelize (C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:233:18)
>       at Object. (C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start\models\index.js:29:17)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (C:\wamp\www\zona_proves\plugins\sheets-api-master\start\routes.js:24:14)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)

Comment: El mensaje de error solicita que por favor instales el paquete sqlite3 manualmente. Seguramente en las instrucciones de instalación se indican los pasos previos que deben realizarse ¿existen esas instrucciones?¿las leíste?

Comment: tal vez faltó un `npm install;`